# Show/hide using jQuery cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies

So I've created a simple tip box that fades in on page load, with an option to close the box. I'm trying to make the box hidden if the visitor clicks the close link. I'm fairly new to cookies, so I'm probably doing it all wrong, but this is what I have:

```
    $('#close').click(function(e) {
        jQuery.cookie('tip', 'hide', cookieOpts);
        $(this).parent('div.tip').fadeOut(1000);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    jQuery.cookie('tip', 'show', cookieOpts);

    $('.tip').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);

    var shouldShow = jQuery.cookie('tip') == 'show';
    var cookieOpts = {expires: 7, path: '/'};

    if( shouldShow ) { 
        $('.tip').delay(500).fadeIn(1000); 
    }
    else {            
        $('.tip').css('display', 'none');
    }
```

Comment: Have you included the cookie JavaScript file?

Comment: Yes, I have included the cookie file. Just don't get why it isn't working. :/

Answer (score 1):

I revised the code:

http://jsbin.com/ujixi4/4/edit

A little bit simpler, hopefully achieves what you want.

```
var cookieOpts = {expires: 7, path: '/'};  //this isnt working for some reason
alert('c: '+$.cookie('tip')); //debug code

if( $.cookie('tip') == 'hide'){
  //do nothing
}else{
  $('.tip').delay(500).fadeIn(1000); 
  //$.cookie('tip', 'hide', {expires: 7, path: '/'}); // Add this if you want the cookie to disappear on reload (even if they don't click)
}

$('#close').click(function(e) {
  $.cookie('tip', 'hide', {expires: 7, path: '/'});
  $('.tip').hide();  
});
```

Here is a similar awnser using cookies:
[jquery change font-size based on cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963985/jquery-change-font-size-based-on-cookie/4964138#4964138)

http://jsbin.com/ufetu5/2/edit

Comment: The fading works, I want the tip to not show once the user visits again. I'm not getting that effect.

Comment: Not sure if it's working exactly. The alert comes up null even after reloading the page. Hm

Comment: So you want it to disappear on reload even if they don't press the close button? I have added that in (see the comment).

Comment: Not exactly. My plan was for it to disappear only on click, otherwise it remains there.

Comment: Ok the problem is with cookieOpts - its breaking it somehow. This one works - http://jsbin.com/ujixi4/6

Comment: I guess I'm going something wrong. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: An upvote would be nice :) I corrected my code, I found an additional problem - http://jsbin.com/ujixi4/6

Comment: Did you try my revised code? Remember the cookie will still be there unless you clear all cookies from your browser.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but I'm not getting the same result as your jsbin.

Comment: Are you using firebug? If there are any other errors in the javascript it will stop working. Also it may depend on the server how the cookies work, might want to try this out and test it in other places.

Comment: It's working now! I was using firebug, but no avail. I removed the var cookieOpts and it started working. Quite odd. Thanks again though! I really really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Good to hear. Yeah that had problems in my code so I hard coded that.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in `cookieOpts`, but the variable is defined below it.

Shift it up to above where it is referenced first.

Comment: I shifted the variable above but it still isn't doing what I wish it to. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.